# how to upload files mern stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

As the title says: is there an easy way to upload files to mongodb atlas without any third party packages (only express react node mongodb and axios)? please can you show me the frontend and backend and if you need my code then ask

Comment: I personally use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to upload files from the client to the server. then Mongo has [GridFs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs) feature to support file saving.

Comment: I hope you dont want to save the entire file in mongodb. that now a good practice.
Also, you can use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/restyts
to create a route and get the file data as buffer free, no need any other modules.